# Swift 3 error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView!'"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to call the superclass' method `tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:indexPath:)` but I get "Cannot call value of non-function type 'UITableView!'"

```
class TextTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        super.tableView(UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath)

        let EditAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (UITableViewRowAction, IndexPath) in
            ...
        }

    return [EditAction]
    }
}
```

Comment: "Sorry for my English, I'm italian" Your English is fine. It's Swift you're not speaking correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    super.tableView(UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath)
```

When you call a function, you do not pass a *type* but a *value* of that type:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    super.tableView(tableView, editActionsForRowAt: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method with the class name (`UITableView`) as the variable, not the variable itself (`tableView`). Try this instead:

```
super.tableView(tableView, editActionsForRowAt: indexPath)
```

Answer (score -2):

You are using wrong names for the super function, use this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    super.tableView(tableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    let EditAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (UITableViewRowAction, IndexPath) in
       // ...
    }

    return [EditAction]
}
```

Comment: The name is different in Swift 3. This is Swift 3.